# Applying Bindings to Identical Groups of DOM Elements

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I've got a View with a bunch of **identical** forms rendered on the same page, and 
I want to get Knockout's data-binding working for every form on the page.

I render all of the Forms - each of which is in its own PartialView - on the **main view** like this:

```
@Model Forms.Models.ViewModels.MasterViewModel

@foreach (var form in Model.Form.ToList())
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Form", form);
}
```

But because all of the forms are identical, all of them use the same data-binding, and MVC renders them with identical IDs:

**Partial View:**

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.foo)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.foo, new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: foo" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.foo)
```

Is there something I can do to apply Knockout's bindings to every form on the page, or is this a no-can-do (for instance, because of the way MVC doesn't mind rendering HTML `inputs` with identical IDs)?

Comment: Is it really necessary to render the form over and over?  You could bind an observable (say selectedItem) to one instance of the form. Then update the value of the selectedItem observable with whichever data needs to be rendered at the moment.

Comment: With my requirements, each individual form renders as a panel in jQuery Accordion.  The Accordion may have two or more panels with identical forms, and each form has identical input IDs/names, so I'm not sure about how the Knockout ViewModel is going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing how your data is modeled, here is a shot in the dark.

In this, I assume that all the form data is contained in a map, that can be referenced by some key field represented in the server-side model.

```
@foreach (var form in Model.Form.ToList())
{
    <!-- ko with: items[@form.Key] -->
    Html.RenderPartial("_Form", form);
    <!-- /ko -->
}
```

With that example, you might have a single object representing all the models:

```
ko.applyBindings(formData); //assuming formData.items
```

You could modify this slightly if you just want the array but no container:

```
@foreach (var form in Model.Form.ToList())
{
    <!-- ko with: @parent[@form.Key] -->
    Html.RenderPartial("_Form", form);
    <!-- /ko -->
}

...

ko.applyBindings(items);
```

Comment: My model isn't currently set up that way, but it looks like it's going to have to be, and that's not a bad idea.  But how does `ko.applyBindings` work with this kind of setup if I don't know in advance how many times a given form will be rendered on the view?

Comment: Well, if the data doesn't have enough models for the forms, then there will be a binding error. Too many models compared to the number of rendered forms, of course, is not an issue. See update to answer.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct (it does answer the question of how to apply bindings to multiple identical forms: using `ko with:`), but I'm still not sure how the Knockout ViewModel is going to work.  Pretty complicated stuff.